# What kind of formal guarantee does a confidence interval provide after an observation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, probability-inequalities

According to my understanding, $C(X)$ is a random variable defined as follows:

> *Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of distributions (defined by user). Let $\alpha>0$. Let $\theta$ be some parameter of a distribution (e.g.,
> mean). When $C(X)$ satisfies the following inequality for all
> $\mathbb{P}\in \mathcal{P}$: $$ \mathbb{P}(\theta\in C(X)) > 1-\alpha $$
> then $C(X)$ is called a $1-\alpha$ confidence set or interval.*

Though a confidence set $C(X)$ should be a random variable, in many research studies, people refer to determined value $C(x_0)$ as a "confidence set" after observing $X=x_0$. Is there any formal mathematical guarantee regarding $\theta$ and $C(x_0)$? By "formal", I mean that a statement or guarantee that can be determined as true or false as usual mathematical statement. is If not, how can people derive any meaningful insights by finding $C(x_0)$?

Comment: The inequality should be $\ge$ rather than $<$ and the expression might be clearer as $\forall \theta: \, \mathbb{P}( C(X) \ni \theta \mid \theta)\ge 1-\alpha$ since this is a statement about $C(X)$ across the distribution of $X$ given $\theta$ rather than about $\theta$.  There is no guarantee of anything when you find $C(x_0)$; all you know is that this method of constructing the confidence interval should give an interval covering unknown $\theta$ at least a proportion $1-\alpha$ of the time it is used, but does not tell you whether it does or not in the specific case when $X=x_0$

Comment: How can people derive any meaningful insights with *any* statistic, you might as well ask.  That kind of answers itself, doesn't it?